# MVC + Firefox console and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, firefox, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to debug my MVC application with the help of firefox's console.

For instance, to get information on the body element I try to use things like `jQuery("BODY")` and `$("BODY")`.

But the former cause an error `jQuery is undefined` and the latter returns null.

Then I try `$("*")` which returns a XULElement whatever that might be.

I'm completely lost there, is MVC or FireFox doing stranges things on how jQuery usually behave?

---

I have this the page's source :

```
<body>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

And the file exists and is accessible.

Inside the source I make several uses of `$` which work just fine.

I really don't get why it's not working in the firefox console...

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery behavior in MVC is no different.
Check that the page loading jQuery correctly.
Maybe this will help:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/and-jquery-not-defined-problems

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I added a few notes to my question, the important thing being that I apparently load correctly jQuery.

Comment: When I answered you. I don't knew other functions work, sorry. You try test in the console of other browser.
If you can,  tell me the exact code you're trying to run on the console, you may have an error. Is that if it works for one, all must work. Another thing may be the version of jquery.
Sorry for my English, I hope you understand me.